# HTML Button like a ASP.NET Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How can i use HTML button like an ASP.NET Button?

Comment: like a asp.net button? with code-behind you mean?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Html tags attributed with `runat="server"` are called HtmlControls and you need to handle `ServerClick` event.

Markup

```
<button id="button1" runat="server" onserverclick="doIt" >Submit</button>
```

Code behind

```
protected void doIt(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   Response.Write("Hello World!!!");
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Add runat=server to the HTML definition as so:

```
<button id="btnserver" runat="server" .../>
```

That will make it a server control

Comment: like this: <input type="button" runat="server" class="button" name="btnRegister" onclick="btnRegister_Click"/> ????

Comment: protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        btn.Text = "yes";
    }

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can turn html elements in to asp.net by adding `runat="server"` attribute.In that way you can use html button as asp.net in following way:

```
<button id="btnOne" runat="server"></button>
```

Now if you have click events for your button, you can use the onserverclick attribute:

```
<button id="btnOne" runat="server" onserverclick="btnOne_Click"></button>
```